# Daedalus wallet 4.2.0 not syncing

Tags: daedalus, cardano-node, syncing

I have a problem with wallet syncing. In fact, the wallet on my imac is not syncing at all. It's not connected to the network. I tried recommendations from a similar [post](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/daedalus-wallet-not-syncing-and-cardano-node-not-responding), but nothing worked. I tried to even reinstall the wallet from scratch but it's just not syncing.

When I installed the very same version from the very same installation file on macbook, then there was no problem and the wallet started syncing immediately. But I can't keep the wallet on macbook due to the lack of space.

Any idea why the wallet on imac refuses to sync? It all started with an update to 4.1. version.

Many thanks for your help!